The Android emulator exited with code -1073740791 during startup
I'm  trying to run my Flutter project in VS Code but as the title suggested the emulator won't run when I started to debug.
Starting device daemon...
[ERR] The Android emulator exited with code -1073740791 after startup
[ERR] Android emulator stderr:
[ERR] INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 3000:9384:2601:0:e0:9284:2601:0 (2x)
[ERR] WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\muhde\.android\avd\..\avd\Pixel_4_XL_API_34.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
[ERR] added library vulkan-1.dll
[ERR] ERROR:             vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties: Invalid physicalDevice [VUID-vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties-physicalDevice-parameter]
[ERR] Address these issues and try again.

Below I also included SDK tools and platforms that I installed in Android Studio.
SDK Tools
SDK Platforms
I have enabled SVM in the BIOS since I'm using a AMD machines. I also tried to reinstall Flutter SDK, VS Code and Android Studio multiple times. My graphics driver is also updated to the latest version. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Update your emulator SDK and try again to run your app.

Error output should be pasted as text (delimited by triple-back-ticks) rather than embedded as images. This makes it easier to find similar questions using search.

If you are using AMD cpu, you need to update the AMD driver.
